# Frozen Ubuntu 20.04 system on desktop

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, keyboard, mouse

A question please: My PC is "freezing", the program that I am using at that moment does not respond on mouse or keyboard, system gets completely stuck. The program can be Firefox, LibreOffice, or just moving a file.

The PC is dual boot, I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 next to Windows 7. Using Windows 7 on the PC there is no problem, so I do not suspect the keyboard or mouse itself. Keyboard has a PS2 connection, mouse is cordless USB.

```
   <section title="Processor " id="2">
        <entry title="AMD Phenom II X6 1050T" value="15 °C" />
        <entry title="Thuban 45nm Technologie" value="" />
    </section>
    <section title="RAM" id="3">
        <entry title="8,00GB Single-Kanaal DDR3 @ 667MHz (9-9-9-24)" value="" />
    </section>
    <section title="Moederbord " id="4">
        <entry title="ASRock 870 Extreme3 (CPUSocket)" value="23 °C" />
    </section>
    <section title="Grafisch" id="5">
        <entry title="PL2530H (1920x1080@60Hz)" value="" />
        <entry title="NVIDIA GeForce 8400 GS (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM v1.1) (MSI)" value="" />
    </section>
```

Any clue please ?

System set up:

@heynnema, the required information: free-h
mem: total 7.8 GI
used 712 MI
free 6.5 GI
shared 1.0 MI
buff/cache 590 Mi
available 6.8 Gi

swap: total 2.0 GI
used 0B
free 2.0 Gi

swappines = 60

swapon -s

filename /swapfile
size 2097148
used -2

I just had time enough to execute the requested command, then the system froze again. I have used the Windows side of the PC to edit this question.

@heynnema: Just to see if it would make a difference: I installed version 18.04 Bionic Beaver, and the problem does not occur up till now. One of these days I will install Kino, this was the only extra program that I had under 20.04. If the problem does not occur in the next few days I will remove the post. Thanks for your attention and help !

Comment: How much RAM do you have? What are the specifications of the computer? Is there a dedicated graphics card? Please edit the question to add these information.

Comment: (1) The system is old so the current standard Ubuntu is likely too much. You should try a lighter flavor like Lubuntu or Xubuntu. (2) the graphics card works best with Nvidia proprietary drivers but the latest version supporting it is 340.

Comment: As far as I know the system requiremens for Ubuntu 20.04 are: 2 GHz dual core processor
4 GiB RAM (system memory)
25 GB of hard drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
VGA capable of 1024×768 screen resolution

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `swapon -s`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Thanks for the info update in your question. Be sure to flag me with a comment that starts with @heynnema or I'll miss the updates/comments. Edit your question again and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Thanks!